# nginx - как записать правило из .htaccess

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Есть правила для apache:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ ?env=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ &controller=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/api/([^/]+)$ api/index.php?env=$1&method=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/ajax.php$ core/ajax.php?env=$1 [QSA,L]

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Переводчик сделал так:

```
rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)$ /?env=$1 break;
rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ /&controller=$2 break;
rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/api/([^/]+)$ /api/index.php?env=$1&method=$2 break;
rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/ajax.php$ /core/ajax.php?env=$1 break;
```

Но адрес https://hello.ru/privet/ajax.php отдает 404 Not Found
А адрес https://hello.ru/privet/api/item.get отдает содержимое файла /api/index.php как текст...

Answer (score 0):

Замените `break` на `last`. C `last` поиск начнётся заново и попадёт в нужный `location ~ \.php$ {`

И используя [этот конвертер](https://www.getpagespeed.com/apache-to-nginx) получаем:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    charset utf-8;
    rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)$ /?env=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ /&controller=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/api/([^/]+)$ /api/index.php?env=$1&method=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/ajax.php$ /core/ajax.php?env=$1 last;
}
```